# Tap recognizer only working in first cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with one prototype cell and I added a long press gesture recognizer that has an action in code like this:

```
 @IBAction func Itinerario(sender: AnyObject) {

    let a = self.tabla
    let b: String = "\n"
    let c: String = "\n"
    let d: String = "*Lugar Destacado"
    let sum = a + b + c + d

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Itinerario de Procesión", message: "\(sum)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Atrás", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(action1)


    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);



}
```

But when I run the project, it is only working for the first cell of the table. How can I make it work for all of them?

Comment: add your code for the cellforrowatindex (whatever the swift equivalent is).  I don't know for sure yet but you probably only added the recognizer to the first cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console, fairly sure you will see an error for iOS 9 and up. Move the gesture recognizer from the cell to the table view and say:

```
@IBAction func Itinerario(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //if you need the cell or index path 
    let location = sender.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if indexPath != nil
    {
      let a = self.tabla
      let b: String = "\n"
      let c: String = "\n"
      let d: String = "*Lugar Destacado"
      let sum = a + b + c + d

      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Itinerario de Procesión", message: "\(sum)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
      let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Atrás", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

      alert.addAction(action1)


      self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }


}
```

Comment: I am getting an error in line `let location = sender.location` it says `Value of type UIGestureRecognizer has no member location`

Comment: Try changing it to UITapGestureRecognizer. Thought they all had location, but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for my App! Now it works!!! :)
Thx so much a @beyowulf!!!

```
        // MARK: - Long Press Gesture Action Sheet
    @IBAction func popUpActionCell(longPressGesture : UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        // Delete selected Cell
        let point = longPressGesture.location(in: self.collectionView)
        let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: point)
//        let cell = self.collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath!)
        if indexPath != nil
        {
            let alertActionCell = UIAlertController(title: "Action Recipe Cell", message: "Choose an action for the selected recipe", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

            // Configure Remove Item Action
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
                RecipeDataManager.shared.recipes.remove(at: indexPath!.row)
                print("Cell Removed")
                self.collectionView!.reloadData()
            })

            // Configure Cancel Action Sheet
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { acion in
                print("Cancel actionsheet")
            })

            alertActionCell.addAction(deleteAction)
            alertActionCell.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alertActionCell, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
```